# Searching for strings in a list within a list in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to determine best way to search the values of my dictionary keys.

I cant seem to find a function that will allow me to search for specific strings within a list of lists.  I am trying to get the program to display semesters that a certain class type was taken.

i.e. input "ENGR" and have it return that it shows up in "fall14","fall15", and "spring16".

Can someone point me in the right direction regarding the pulling of data from a list within a list? I am thinking I may need to restructure the way I defined my keys.

```
Classes = dict()
Classes["FALL14"] = ("ENGR","156","01",'Engineering 3'),("ENGR","156","01",'Engineering 4'),("SCI","156","01",'Chemistry 1'),("ENGL","156","01",'Writing 1')
Classes['SPRING15'] =("ENGL","156","01",'Writing 2'),("MATH","156","01",'Calculus 1'),("MATH","156","01",'Calculus 2'),("MATH","156","01",'Calculus 3')
Classes['FALL15'] =("MATH","156","01",'Differential Equations'),("ENGR","156","01",'Solid Works'),("ENGR","156","01",'MATLAB'),("ENGR","156","01",'Dynamics')
Classes['SPRING16'] = ("ENGR","156","01",'Statics'),("ART","156","01",'Drawing 1'),("ENGR","156","01",'Fluid Dynamics'),("ENGR","156","01",'Thermodynamics 1')


for semester, information in Classes.items():   #Prints semesters that a class type was taken.
    if information ==  "ENGR":
        print(semester)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the string you want to compare will always be at the 0th index of your nested tuple, you may match the content using [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) like:

```
my_str = "ENGR"

#                             v  as per PEP naming convention, it should 
#                             v  start with lower-case
for semester, informations in Classes.items():
    if any(item[0]==my_str for item in informations):
        #       ^  check element at 0th index of each sub-tuple 
        #          for the match with `my_str`
        print(semester)  # OR, print(semester.lower()) to print the lower cased
                         # string as mentioned in desired result
```

which will print:

```
FALL14
FALL15
SPRING16
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go another level down. Your loop gives you a list of sets. You then need to iterate over those sets

```
Classes = dict()
Classes["FALL14"] = ("ENGR","156","01",'Engineering 3'),("ENGR","156","01",'Engineering 4'),("SCI","156","01",'Chemistry 1'),("ENGL","156","01",'Writing 1')
Classes['SPRING15'] =("ENGL","156","01",'Writing 2'),("MATH","156","01",'Calculus 1'),("MATH","156","01",'Calculus 2'),("MATH","156","01",'Calculus 3')
Classes['FALL15'] =("MATH","156","01",'Differential Equations'),("ENGR","156","01",'Solid Works'),("ENGR","156","01",'MATLAB'),("ENGR","156","01",'Dynamics')
Classes['SPRING16'] = ("ENGR","156","01",'Statics'),("ART","156","01",'Drawing 1'),("ENGR","156","01",'Fluid Dynamics'),("ENGR","156","01",'Thermodynamics 1')

for semester, information in Classes.items():   
    for classes in information:
         if 'ENGR' in classes:
                 print classes
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. You need to keep drilling down into your data structures.

```
Classes = dict()
Classes["FALL14"] = ("ENGR","156","01",'Engineering 3'),("ENGR","156","01",'Engineering 4'),("SCI","156","01",'Chemistry 1'),("ENGL","156","01",'Writing 1')
Classes['SPRING15'] =("ENGL","156","01",'Writing 2'),("MATH","156","01",'Calculus 1'),("MATH","156","01",'Calculus 2'),("MATH","156","01",'Calculus 3')
Classes['FALL15'] =("MATH","156","01",'Differential Equations'),("ENGR","156","01",'Solid Works'),("ENGR","156","01",'MATLAB'),("ENGR","156","01",'Dynamics')
Classes['SPRING16'] = ("ENGR","156","01",'Statics'),("ART","156","01",'Drawing 1'),("ENGR","156","01",'Fluid Dynamics'),("ENGR","156","01",'Thermodynamics 1')


for semester, information in Classes.items():   #Prints semesters that a class type was taken.    
    for course_info in Classes[semester]:
        if course_info[0] ==  "ENGR":
            print(semester)
```

Comment: Since you are already iterating using `dict.items()`, you should replace `Classes[semester]` with `information `